# Adjust right edge position of Word table with merged columns using Excel macro

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I am working on a macro to format and extract information from a number of word documents that all have 1 table in it.  The problem is that this table has many rows, and each each row has either 1, 2, or 3 columns in it, and I need to ensure that the right edge of the table is always the same width.

The actual behaviour that I want to replicate in VBA code is when you drag the little square thing on the ruler bar in word (that represents the right edge of the table) to adjust the right edge of the table for all rows.  However, when I try and record a macro, it generates the following line of code, which does not work for tables with merged columns:

```
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=501.3, RulerStyle:= _
    wdAdjustNone
```

Next I tried to explicitly target just the first row using the following code.  This worked, but it only resized the width for the first row - all of the other rows were unchanged:

```
    wdApp.Documents(myDoc).Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=501.3, RulerStyle:=_ 
    wdAdjustNone
```

I then played around with the .width property, rather than the .setwdith property, but they seemed to behave the same.  I even tried all four .setwidth RulerStyle parameters but they all behaved the same.

Finally, in frustration, I decided to loop through all of the rows in the table, and resize the rightmost column as needed so the entire row is my desired 501.3 pixels.  This took some doing, as I could not find a way to tell how many columns are on a given row.  I ended up relying on trapped errors to solve the issue - see below.  The 4th row will error when there are not enough columns on that row, so I simply reduce the i variable and try again until there is no error:

```
On Error GoTo BadExit
    For row = 1 To wdApp.Documents(myDoc).Tables(1).Rows.count
        i = 3
        If wdApp.Documents(myDoc).Tables(1).Cell(row, i).PreferredWidth <> 1501.3 Then
            If i = 3 Then
                wid = 501.3 - wdApp.Documents(myDoc).Tables(1).Cell(row, 2).Width - wdApp.Documents(myDoc).Tables(1).Cell(row, 1).Width
                wdApp.Documents(myDoc).Tables(1).Cell(row, i).Width = wid
            ElseIf i = 2 Then
                wid = 501.3 - wdApp.Documents(myDoc).Tables(1).Cell(row, 1).Width
                wdApp.Documents(myDoc).Tables(1).Cell(row, i).Width = wid
            Else
                wid = 501.3
                wdApp.Documents(myDoc).Tables(1).Cell(row, i).Width = wid
            End If

        End If

        GoTo SafeExit
BadExit:
        If i = 3 Then
            i = 2
            Resume
        ElseIf i = 2 Then
            i = 1
            Resume
        End If

SafeExit:
    Next row
```

This code runs through with no errors however the final width never seems to be 501.3 - it seems to vary inconsistently (which I confirmed by using msgbox with the .width property), and also, sometimes the right edges are not lined up!  The rows with 1 column may stick out a bit further than the rows with 2 columns, etc.  And this code is very slow.

Can anybody help me find a simple solution to replicate the behavior of manually using your mouse to move the right square on the ruler to adjust the width of every row in a word table to a specific value?  Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
-Josh